# How to use a regular expression inside TermDocumentMatrix for text mining?

Tags: regex, r, text-mining, tm

I know that I can use the tm package to count the occurrences of specific words in a corpus using the Dictionary function:

```
require(tm)
data(crude)

dic <- Dictionary("crude")
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(crude, control = list(dictionary = dic, removePunctuation = TRUE))
inspect(tdm)
```

I would like to know if there is a facility to instead supply a regular expression to Dictionary instead of a fixed word?

Sometimes stemming may not be what I want (e.g. I may want to pick up spelling mistakes ) and so I would like to do something like:

```
dic <- Dictionary(c("crude", 
                    "\\bcrud[[:alnum:]]+"),
                    "\\bcrud[de]")
```

and thus continue to use the facilities of the tm package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that you can put regex in the dictionary function as it only accepts a character vector or a term-document matrix. The work-around I'd suggest is using regex to subset the terms in the term-document matrix, then do word counts:

```
# What I would do instead
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(crude, control = list(removePunctuation = TRUE))
# subset the tdm according to the criteria
# this is where you can use regex
crit <- grep("cru", tdm$dimnames$Terms)
# have a look to see what you got
inspect(tdm[crit])
        A term-document matrix (2 terms, 20 documents)

    Non-/sparse entries: 10/30
    Sparsity           : 75%
    Maximal term length: 7 
    Weighting          : term frequency (tf)

             Docs
    Terms     127 144 191 194 211 236 237 242 246 248 273 349 352 353 368 489 502 543
      crucial   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
      crude     2   0   2   3   0   2   0   0   0   0   5   2   0   2   0   0   0   2
             Docs
    Terms     704 708
      crucial   0   0
      crude     0   1
# and count the number of times that criteria is met in each doc
colSums(as.matrix(tdm[crit]))
127 144 191 194 211 236 237 242 246 248 273 349 352 353 368 489 502 543 704 708 
  2   0   2   3   0   2   2   0   0   0   5   2   0   2   0   0   0   2   0   1 
# count the total number of times in all docs
sum(colSums(as.matrix(tdm[crit])))
[1] 23
```

If this isn't what you want, go ahead and edit your question to include some example data that is properly representative of your actual use-case, and an example of your desired output.

Answer (score 2):

The text analysis package **quanteda** allows feature selection using regular expressions, if you specify `valuetype = "regex"`.

```
require(tm)
require(quanteda)
data(crude)

dfm(corpus(crude), keptFeatures = "^cru", valuetype = "regex", verbose = FALSE)
# Document-feature matrix of: 20 documents, 2 features.
# 20 x 2 sparse Matrix of class "dfmSparse"
#      features
# docs  crude crucial
#   127     2       0
#   144     0       0
#   191     2       0
#   194     3       0
#   211     0       0
#   236     2       0
#   237     0       2
#   242     0       0
#   246     0       0
#   248     0       0
#   273     5       0
#   349     2       0
#   352     0       0
#   353     2       0
#   368     0       0
#   489     0       0
#   502     0       0
#   543     2       0
#   704     0       0
#   708     1       0
```

See also `?selectFeatures`.